# Defining a string type with disallowed/forbidden characters

Tags: typescript, template-literals

I want to create a type for a string that can contain any characters, except for a specified list of disallowed/forbidden characters - for example:

```
type StringWithNoSlash = // ...

const x: StringWithNoSlash = 'abc' // no error
const y: StringWithNoSlash = 'ab/' // error
```

Is this possible in TypeScript?

Comment: Yes but you'll need a helper function to do incentivize TypeScript to infer/validate the string.

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/mxY4zW) is how that would look like. This is not possible using a plain declaration with type annotation like `const x: StringWithNoSlash`, at least not yet.

Comment: I'm trying to narrow a function argument, so this is perfect for me! Thank you!